# ARCore/SceneForm Display model wireframe mode

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I have implemented **Arcore** with **SceneForm** in my android app but now I'm facing a problem because I did not find a way to display model wireframe.

This is the result I want to get:
[image]

I follow this guide for the implementation: https://medium.com/@harivigneshjayapalan/arcore-cupcakes-1-render-a-scene-without-ar-for-phones-without-arcore-27d61a43a130

In **iOS SceneKit** there's a way by setting `fillMode = .lines`:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterial/2867442-fillmode

Comment: Hello, I have the same need. Did you get the solution to perform a wireframe display with SceneForm / Filament?

Comment: Hello @jadoux I didn't find any way to implement it. So I ended up using https://github.com/the3deers/android-3D-model-viewer and adapting it to my use case.